# How to simulate DFS recursive return call using iteration?

Tags: recursion, iteration

I understand the iterative DFS code [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-depth-first-traversal/).
However, it seems to me that when we use iteration, we can only simulate the *forward* recursive calls of DFS, and not the return statements. For example, if I want to calculate **N!** using an iteration-simulated version of the recursive solution, we cannot achieve it.

Am I correct with this conclusion?
A counter example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear where you're confused -- which may be a result of your confusion.  The iterative cognate of a **return** isn't explicit; it's a different process.  The control flow is to simply return to the top of the loop.  The data flow depends on the algorithm: you pop an item off a stack, or store a result in an array, for example.

If "nth factorial" is the mathematical N! computation, the iterative **return** is simply the next loop iteration, with the partial product stored in a local variable:

```
# value of n is given
prod = 1

for i in range(n, 1, -1):
    prod *= i

# yield prod as result
```